# regex to catch words in pre defined placeholders

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm creating a function in PHP that takes a string . Then the function must look within that string , words within brackets and saves them in an array. Is there any function to conduct the search only those words and save them to an array? or in a variable and then I pass it to an array ?

String example

```
 <font color="maroon">[como]</font>  &lt;rel&gt; &lt;ks&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-ADVL</font></b> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-N&lt;</font></b>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">não</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[não]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">amar</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[amar]</font>  &lt;vt&gt; <font color="blue"><b>V</b> FUT 1/3S SUBJ VFIN </font> <font color="darkgreen">@FMV</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">uma</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[um]</font>  &lt;arti&gt; <font color="blue"><b>DET</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;N</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">pessoa</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[pessoa]</font>  &lt;H&gt; <font color="blue"><b>N</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&lt;ACC</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">tão</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[tão]</font>  &lt;dem&gt; &lt;quant&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;A</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">linda</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[lindo]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADJ</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@N&lt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">.</font></b>
```

Array example

```
Array
(
    [0] => como
    [1] => não
    [2] => amar
    [3] => um
    [5] => pessoa
    [6] => tão
    [7] => lindo

)
```

Comment: `Is there any function`. It's called `preg_match`

Comment: @LucasMelo Shouldn't you be parsing the (ancient) HTML instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you are looking for is the `preg_match_all()` function

```
$htmlToParse = 'Some [html] here to be [captured] and [filtered]';
preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $htmlToParse, $matchesWords);

print_r($matchesWords);
```

and there will be something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => html
    [1] => captured
    [2] => filtered
)
```

See the full documentation of [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function and keep studying some of **regular expression** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 1):

Use a paser then a regex. This will scan all `font` elements. It then checks the content of that element and returns values inside `[]`.

```
$html = '<font color="maroon">[como]</font>  &lt;rel&gt; &lt;ks&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-ADVL</font></b> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-N&lt;</font></b>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">não</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[não]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">amar</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[amar]</font>  &lt;vt&gt; <font color="blue"><b>V</b> FUT 1/3S SUBJ VFIN </font> <font color="darkgreen">@FMV</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">uma</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[um]</font>  &lt;arti&gt; <font color="blue"><b>DET</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;N</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">pessoa</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[pessoa]</font>  &lt;H&gt; <font color="blue"><b>N</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&lt;ACC</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">tão</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[tão]</font>  &lt;dem&gt; &lt;quant&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;A</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">linda</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[lindo]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADJ</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@N&lt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">.</font></b> ';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('font');
foreach ($tags as $foundtag) {
    if(preg_match('~\[(.*?)\]~', $foundtag->nodeValue, $value)) {
        echo $value[1] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
como
não
amar
um
pessoa
tão
lindo
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wZ6fL9/1

Write up:

`~` is a delimiter tells where regex starts and ends 
`\[` escapes the `[` so it is a literal search for `[`.
`(.*?)` searches and captures (because of `()`, http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) anything between the `[` and `]` (change `*` to `+` if you require something be present).